# Primefaces handler to penult tab

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I decided to use wizard component.[link on this component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf)

I have condition that instead of checkbox "Skip to last" I should use button. If I press on this button it's ok, but when I go to penult tab I want generate content of confirmation tab,

```
public void generatePreview() {

        for (CompetitionTypeBean competitionType : competitionTypeList) {
            if (competitionType.getId().equals(competitionTypeId)) {
                tournamentBean.setCompetitionTypeBean(competitionType);
            }
        }
 if (teamList != null && !teamList.isEmpty()) {
            List<TeamBean> teams = new ArrayList<TeamBean>();
            for (TeamBean team : teamList) {
                for (Long teamId : teamListSelected)
                    if (team.getId().equals(teamId)) {
                        teams.add(team);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            tournamentBean.setTeams(teams);
        }
    }
```

it means that I should set `skip in true` for that I decide to write js function which `will work on onnext event of wizard`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function setHiddenValue(formId, componentId, new_value) {

            var tabId = 'competitionId';
            if (tabId != 'predLast') {
                document.getElementsByName('wiz').next();
            } else {
                var fullComponentId = formId + ":" + componentId;
                document.getElementById(fullComponentId).value = new_value;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And there I find new problem

First I don't know as I can get current Tab Id. And second I don't how with help js make next event for wizard `document.getElementsByName('wiz').next();`. I try to see generated html code. Every tab is `<li>` and when this tab is selected in css style that li add 'ui-state-hightlight'

Maybe I try to develop cycle. But I can't find other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add next rows in handler

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) throws Exception {
        if ((skip == true)) {
            skip = false;   //reset in case user goes back
            generatePreview();
            return CONFIRM_TAB_ID;
        } else {
            String newTab = event.getNewStep();
            if (CONFIRM_TAB_ID.equals(newTab)) {
                generatePreview();
            }

            return newTab;
        }
    }
```

I think that using constant CONFIRM_TAB_ID it's normal, because I never decide to change this tabId.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get the index of the current step in javascript, use the `getStepIndex()` function. To get **name** of the current step in the backing bean, you need to obtain a reference to the Wizard in your view and either call `getStep()`(returns the `id` property of the next tab) or `getStepToProcess()`(returns the actual next `Tab` object, from which you can get the name of the current tab).
2. `<p:wizard/>` has `onnext` and `onback` event callbacks that you can hook into to process javascript (or backing bean code with `<p:remoteCommand/>`)